# determine start of file when passing multipe files to awk

Tags: shell-script, awk

I have a shell script like the following -

> find "." "Account" -maxdepth 1 -name "*.aspx" | xargs awk -f get_controls.awk

It passes multiple files to an awk script

```
BEGIN{
    FS="\""
}
...
/Src=/{
    printf("\t%s \r\n", $6);
}
```

I want to print out the current file name either from the shell script or from within awk at the start of the file.

Awk does know the current file name, it is in the FILENAME variable, but I can't determine the start of the file.
I have tried `(NR==1)`, but all the files are passed to awk as a stream and the value of NR keeps increasing.

Just figured it out as I type this. Will post answer below!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to `NR`, which counts all records processed thus far, awk has an [`FNR`](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#index-g_t_0040code_007bFNR_007d-variable-1252) variable, which counts the records in the current file.

To print the filename when you see the first line of a file:

```
awk 'FNR == 1 {print "now processing " FILENAME}' file ...
```

If you have access to `gawk`, you also get, in addition to `BEGIN` and `END` blocks, [`BEGINFILE` and `ENDFILE`](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#BEGINFILE_002fENDFILE) blocks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I figured out while typing the question, sometimes I forget to think of awk as a programming language.

```
#! /usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN{
    FS="\""
    OLDFILENAME=""
}


/Src=/{
    if(OLDFILENAME != FILENAME) 
    {
          printf("\r\n%s  \r\n", FILENAME);
          OLDFILENAME=FILENAME
        }
    printf("\t%s \r\n", $6);
}
```